# Jittering lines when scrolling a TMX map in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

I feel like I'm missing some fundamental concept as to why I am getting flickering when moving a tile map around.

I create a layer. In it, I add a TMXTiledMap.

```
_tileMap = TMXTiledMap::create("TMX/32Map.tmx");
_tileMap->setScale(1.f);
_floorLayer = _tileMap->getLayer("Floor");
this->addChild(_tileMap);
for(const auto& l : _tileMap->getChildren()) {
    static_cast<SpriteBatchNode*>(l)->getTexture()->setAliasTexParameters();
}
this->scheduleUpdate();
```

In the update I move the layer.

```
Vec2 newPos = this->getPosition();
newPos.x = (newPos.x - 1);
newPos.y = (newPos.y - 1);
this->setPosition(newPos);
```

I realize I'm not moving it by dt. If I move it by dt I get an overall jumpiness to the whole layer. I understand this is due to how it renders partial pixels. But if I move it by one pixel like above, I get this # looking set of lines on the screen about 64 pixels or so on top and bottom and about 224 pixels from the left and right

That is when the window is 1024x768. If I make a 320x240 window, I don't see the lines and if I make it 640x480 I only see them on the left and right sides right near the edge of the screen.

Ultimately I'd just like to smoothly scroll a tile map around. Any help would be super appreciated, because I just can't seem to get started on this project.

Comment: Same problem. Do you solve that ? Maybe move map only by certain distance, or move only by even numbers.

Comment: I am currently using TexturePacker to add buffers around the tiles. I'm not sure this is 100% "solved" because I have been staring at it so long that everything looks weird to me, but as I delve further into the project I'll be able to tell if this really is what I needed or not.

Answer (score 1):

For me working solution was to change CC_FIX_ARTIFACTS_BY_STRECHING_TEXEL in ccConfig.h from 1 to 0. Find ccConfig.h in cocos/base/.

Comment: This only made things look gross on my end.